# Solving for complex $a_n$ in a harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

Is there any way to know for what values of $a$ and $b$, the following is true?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{a+b*i}} = 0$$

Comment: Maybe we'll know in 100 years:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis

Comment: @AlexR. Exactly!